# Customizing a nginx configuration doesn't works after swapping domain on Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I was trying to custom a nginx configuation by adding `.platform/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf` with content `client_max_body_size 50M;` into my project. After deploying successfully I tried calling api to it and everything was fine, But after swapping domain with another environment it started to not response to client and i saw it response only 499 in `/var/log/nginx/access.log`.

*Platform verison: Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.6.0*

What did i try.

- Tried to add scipts into .ebextensions and .platform for restart nginx/app but these seems not to works when swapping domain
- I also tried to connect to the instance for restarting nginx but it does not back to works normally.
- It will back to be normal after restart the application by running `docker restart <container_id>` in the instance.

I have no idea how to make it works by not manually restarting the app every single deployment.